# does Kamcord also support sharing of screenshots?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I would like to know if Kamcord can also be used to share screen snapshots? If yes, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I have not done it yet, but I believe you are looking for what is handled by two functions defined in their headers:

```
+ (UIImage *)snapshot;

+ (BOOL)snapshotNextFrameWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(UIImage * image, NSURL * imageURL))handler saveToURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL;
```

Check out their header for a description of those functions purpose:
https://github.com/kamcord/kamcord-ios-sdk/blob/master/Kamcord.embeddedframework/Kamcord.framework/Headers/Kamcord.h

(This is all as of v1.7.6)

You are going to have to decide when to call that (i.e., when something interesting happens in your app worthy of a single image.)

Send an email over support@kamcord.com to confirm. They are super responsive to questions like this.

*Edit: Cleaned up grammatical errors*